# Is there a convenient font library for OpenGL-ES 2 like glFont?

Tags: iphone, c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

[Brad Fish's glFont](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~bfish/glfont.php) seems pretty cool.  But it won't work under OpenGL ES 2.0.  Has anyone found a set of font utilities that work in OpenGL-ES 2.0?

I suppose I could port glFont, but it's quite a bit of work.

Comment: I tried FTGLES.  (See my comment below about it not really working out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this](http://code.google.com/p/ftgles/) might be what you're looking for. This is for OpenGL ES 1.1 however, not sure if it's also compatible with 2.0. It should be as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I spent some honest time with it trying to make it work.  It does seem to be adaptable to ES 2.0.  However, it doesn't cross-compile well.  That's it's issue.  It will compile on Mac, but not windows.  So it's really an iPhone-only library developed on a Mac.  For a guy like me who is targeting Android and doing development on Mac and PC, this has been a chore to make work.  I'm going to keep at it.